# Js regex character set including " " or ""

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I want to check if there is a `y` after `x`
my code:

```js
let STR = "x y"
console.log(/xy/g.test(STR) || /x y/g.test(STR))
```

this is working but to make the code better, I want to combine `/xy/g` with `/x y/g` to get one regex but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test for an optional (0 or 1 occurrences) of space between x and y by using the `?` metacharacter:

```js
let STR = "x y"
console.log(/x( )?y/g.test(STR))
```

If you meant to test for an arbitrary number of spaces, use `*` instead of `?`.

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isValid = str => /x\s?y/g.test(str);

console.log( isValid('x y') );
console.log( isValid('xy') );
console.log( isValid('xzy') );
```

If you want to consider 1+ spaces: `\s*`